# To solve why AT SPI Registry closed unexpectly

Tags: 11.10

I get the following error report in 11.10 every time after logging in.
Compiz sometimes too crashes.

[image]

My apport fails to send the data to Launchpad for some reason so the button *Report Problem* not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably cannot report the crash because your system is not up-to-date (but you should have gotten a message about *why* sending the report failed).

If that's that case I suggest to update your system using the main servers:

- Open the Ububuntu Software Center
- *Edit → Software Sources... → Download from: Main server*

Then update your system and wait for the Apport popup to appear again.

Of course you can also just click on *Ignore future crashes of this program version*.

Comment: I have had main server in the settings. I hate to ignore. Seems that the best way is to reinstall the whole OS.